# ¿Cómo se denomina a este tipo de hoja?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-término

El otro día estaba ojeando un libro de un juego de rol cuando me encontré con la siguiente ilustración, que muestra un puñal cuya hoja se curva varias veces.

Sé que en ciertas espadas, como los sables o las cimitarras, la hoja se curva un poco, pero desconozco el nombre de este tipo de puñal o estilo de hoja corta en la que la misma se curva varias veces.

¿Cómo se denomina al diseño de este tipo de hoja?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si bien esa arma en particular es un kris, al tipo de hoja se lo conoce como *flamígero* u *ondulado*; en Europa ha sido más común encontrarlo en [espadas de gran tamaño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espada_flam%C3%ADgera).

Answer (score 6):

Su nombre es **Kris**: http://dle.rae.es/?id=MiIHjgF ; https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kris .

Como dice en el link de la wikipedia, es originaria de Indonesia, específicamente de la isla de Java, si no recuerdo mal, y en la realidad suele tener un fuerte componente ritual más que un uso bélico; que no es que no tenga este último, no deja de ser un arma, pero que yo sepa siempre ha sido conocida por ese componente ritual.

En los juegos de rol, sobre todo en los de ambientación medieval/fantástica, es muy típica de personajes del tipo ladrón y asesino. También en las novelas del género es relativamente común para ese tipo de personajes, lo cual resulta bastante lógico dada su forma y su fama: siempre consigues dar un tono esotérico o místico.

Comment: (+1) According to the English version on Wikipedia it was in fact used in action and was not purely ceremonial. The English version is much fuller and well worth a look.

Comment: Correct both, English Wikipedia is usually fuller and Kryss was (or is, who knows) used as a weapon, not only ceremonial. I think I said it at the answer :)